# Exception when attempting to authenticate to AD using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

Tags: c#

Want to share with the community a recent exception I encountered after our network folks enabled channel binding on our AD. The change was inspired by [KB4520412](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows-kb4520412-ef185fb8-00f7-167d-744c-f299a66fc00a)

My initial code logic was as follows and worked flawlessly up until the recent change.

```
 var cred = new NetworkCredential(credentials.UserId, credentials.Password);
 var serverId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(host, port);

 using var conn = new LdapConnection(serverId, cred);
 conn.Bind();
```

After the change my code started receiving exceptions
"The supplied credential is invalid"
Inner Exception
"80090346: LdapErr: DSID-0C09059A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 80090346, v3839"

To remedy the exception I changed my code to the below.

```
using var conn = new LdapConnection(serverId, cred,AuthType.Basic);
               
conn.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
conn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
conn.SessionOptions.FastConcurrentBind();

conn.Bind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remedied the exception by implementing a change to the session options as follows.

```
using var conn = new LdapConnection(serverId, cred,AuthType.Basic);

conn.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
conn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
conn.SessionOptions.FastConcurrentBind();

conn.Bind();
```